# Como podría abrir un pdf en Android Studio desde una aplicación, con el lector de pdf predeterminado?. con el api 27 hacia delante

Tags: java, android

Mi pregunta es ¿Como podría abrir un pdf en Android desde una aplicación, con el lector de pdf predeterminado? requiero que sea con el api 27 hacia delante. Tengo definido : `targetSdkVersion 29`

He usado varios códigos pero me emite error cuando quiero ejecutar.

```
private void AbrirPDF(Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Visualizando documento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Tracking/" + nombPdf;
    Log.i("OpenpffDIR",dir);
    File arch = new File(dir);
    Log.i("RUTA", arch.getPath());

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(arch.getPath()),"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No existe una aplicación para abrir el PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Julio, gracias por editar tu pregunta, recuerda que es importante verificar cual es el error que se muestra, eso puede dar más idea de que es lo que sucede, por cierto no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar las siguientes líneas de código:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ 
filename); //Obtienes la ruta del archivo
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf"); //Aquí especificamos el tipo de archivo
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File"); //En esta línea establecemos que se muestren las aplicaciones que pueden leer un PDF
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Aquí podemos arrojar un mensaje para que el usuario sepa que quizás no tiene una app que lea PDF's 
}
```